Getting warning in expo router [ Layout children ] : No route named "(tabs)" exists in nested children ["+not-found","_sitemap"]
I was working on an app made with react-native expo it was all working fine and it is a very large project but suddenly the expo changed its version of sdk and it stopped working instead it displayed a message on a blue screen that "either use an older version of expo go app or upgrade to the latest version of sdk " then i updated to the latest version of expo go and then when i started my app it never started i have been trying to start it from many time it is about a month and half to me trying to start it but it is not starting instead it displays a +not-found screen as
enter image description here
and display me a warning that
enter image description here
my folder structure is as
app / (tabs)/_layout.jsx,_layout.jsx ,index.jsx ,+html.jsx,+not-found.jsx,
(inside the app folder there is folder named as tabs and four files (,_layout.jsx ,index.jsx ,+html.jsx,+not-found.jsx ) inside tabs folder there is a file _layout.jsx  )
please can anyone tell how can i fix it is a very larger project and i cannot afford to lose it
I tried everything that i can even when it not started i maded a new project of expo go and transfered all of the contents there but still i am getting the warning and my project is not working

In my case, I solved the issue by making the function default.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

thank you @Yavuz, you are correct, my components were using export function MyComponent(){}  so I changed to expor default function MyComponent and it worked
